# Get the function name from it's body in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function

Say I have a function:

```
def foo()
puts getFunctionIAMIn()
end
```

I want the output to be:"foo"
And if I have this code:

```
def foo1()
puts getFunctionIAMIn()
end
```

I want the output to be:"foo1"

Comment: The question, in a different phrasing, how do I realize getFunctionIAMIn() ?

Answer (score 5):

Just write as below using [`__method__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__):

```
def foo()
  puts __method__
end
```

Above is correct, but [`__callee__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) sounds more technically correct.

`__method__` returns defined name, and `__callee__` returns called name.[They are same usually, but *different in a aliased method.*](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4415281)

```
def foo
  [__method__, __callee__]
end

alias bar foo
p foo #=> [:foo, :foo]
p bar #=> [:foo, :bar]
```

Comment: You beat me by 8 seconds :D

Comment: Do you know how it is different from `__callee__`?

Comment: @sawa Look here https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4415281

Comment: @Stefan No they are not... :)

Comment: @sawa Got your point.. `__callee__` is more technically correct.. Let me edit.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I have *generated* PDFs in many ways but never parsed one. This is still related to the question, right? ;)

Comment: @Stefan Need a help on this.. :) Don't know how would I unstuck me from there.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__method__` for that:

```
def test_method
  __method__
end
```

Comment: Do you thin your answer and my one is different ?